# React.createContext point of defaultValue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On the [React 16 Context doc page](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), they have examples that look similar to this one:

```
const defaultValue = 'light'
const SomeContext = React.createContext(defaultValue)

const startingValue = 'light'
const App = () => (
  <SomeContext.Provider theme={startingValue}>
    Content
  </SomeContext.Provider>
)
```

It seems that the `defaultValue` is useless because if you instead set the `startingValue` to anything else or don't set it (which is `undefined`), it overrides it. That's fine, it should do that.

But then what's the point of the `defaultValue`?

If I want to have a static context that doesn't change, it would be nice to be able to do something like below, and just have the Provider been passed through the `defaultValue`

```
const App = () => (
  <SomeContext.Provider>
    Content
  </SomeContext.Provider>
)
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

When there's no Provider, the `defaultValue` argument is used for the function `createContext`. This is helpful for testing components in isolation without wrapping them, or testing it with different values from the Provider.

---

Code sample:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

const Context = createContext( "Default Value" );

function Child() {
  const context = useContext(Context);
  return <h2>Child1: {context}</h2>;
}

function Child2() {
  const context = useContext(Context);
  return <h2>Child2: {context}</h2>;
}

function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Context.Provider value={ "Initial Value" }>
        <Child /> {/* Child inside Provider will get "Initial Value" */}
      </Context.Provider>
        <Child2 /> {/* Child outside Provider will get "Default Value" */}
    </>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/context-api-defaultvalue-s9ok5)

Comment: from https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext: 
"The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree. This can be helpful for testing components in isolation without wrapping them. Note: passing undefined as a Provider value does not cause consuming components to use defaultValue."

Comment: If you want to create a singleton in your application, is it good practice to only expose the provider of the context (it will always return the default value)?

Comment: So it's again a hack on a top of a hack.

Comment: so mad at this... so there are TWO defaults that are used depending on provider is setup correctly. say provider wasn't setup properly you will be getting 'default' not the initial value and be like why is it wrong

Comment: This is the answer of new documentation of Reactjs: https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext#parameters

Answer (score 49):

Just sharing my typical setup when using TypeScript, to complete answer from @tiomno above, because I think many googlers that ends up here are actually looking for this:

```
interface GridItemContextType {
    /** Unique id of the item */
    i: string;
}
const GridItemContext = React.createContext<GridItemContextType | undefined>(
    undefined
);

export const useGridItemContext = () => {
    const gridItemContext = useContext(GridItemContext);
    if (!gridItemContext)
        throw new Error(
            'No GridItemContext.Provider found when calling useGridItemContext.'
        );
    return gridItemContext;
};
```

The hook provides a safer typing in this scenario. The `undefined` `defaultValue` protects you from forgetting to setup the provider.

Comment: I think this is the best way to do things in TypeScript, assuming there's no meaningful `defaultValue` to supply. Just a note though Eric - you shouldn't need to cast with `as GridItemContextType` at the end because TypeScript should already be able to narrow the type of `gridItemCheck` via your conditional immediately above.

Comment: Yes definitely, it's edited

Comment:  I was looking for a way not to have to do this actually, but I guess I have to. The best part is  that there is no need to wrap around ```if(){}``` when using useGridItemContext later.

Comment: You can make an helper function with a generic type, that returns both the context and the accessor hook with the undefined check if you really have a lot of contexts. I also hate to setup a new context because of the verbosity :)

Comment: THIS IS THE WAY

Answer (score 8):

My two cents:

After reading [this instructive article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively) by Kent C. Dodds as usual :), I learnt that the defaultValue is useful when you destructure the value returned by useContext:

Define the context in one corner of the codebase without defaultValue:

```
const CountStateContext = React.createContext() // <-- define the context in one corner of the codebase without defaultValue
```

and use it like so in a component:

```
const { count } = React.useContext(CountStateContext)
```

JS will obviously say `TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined`

But you can simply not do that and avoid the defaultValue altogether.

About tests, my teacher Kent has a good point when he says:

> The React docs suggest that providing a default value "can be helpful
> in testing components in isolation without wrapping them." While it's
> true that it allows you to do this, I disagree that it's better than
> wrapping your components with the necessary context. Remember that
> every time you do something in your test that you don't do in your
> application, you reduce the amount of confidence that test can give
> you.

**Extra for TypeScript**; if you don't want to use a defaultValue, it's easy to please the lint by doing the following:

```
const MyFancyContext = React.createContext<MyFancyType | undefined>(undefined)
```

You only need to be sure to add the extra validations later on to be sure you have covered the cases when MyFancyContext === undefined

- MyFancyContext ?? 'default'
- MyFancyContext?.notThatFancyProperty

etc

Comment: the article you link to says that `defaultValue` is used when you don't put the consumer in the appropriate provider. It doesn't matter if the returned value is being destructured or not, it's just an example

Comment: Thank you for this!
A while ago I read Dan Abramov's comment about this (the one linked from the d.ts file: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/24509#issuecomment-382213106) and it never 'clicked' for me. But I just followed the directive, because who am I to disagree with someone who knows a thing or two about React and context?

Your quote of KCD (~"test like you run") made me realize what's wrong with `defaultValue`: it allows 'bad' devs to render components that rely on context w/o providing one, while punishing the 'good' devs who build their app properly.

Comment: You can create a custom hook for the context and force a cast:
`const useMyContext = () => { const context = useContext(MyContext); if (!context) throw new Error("MyContext Provider not found"); return context as MyContextType; }`. This way in downstream component, the value is guaranteed to be defined (less checks needed)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the default values using useReducer hook, then the 2nd argument will be the default value:

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { yourReducer } from "./yourReducer";

export const WidgetContext = createContext();

const ContextProvider = (props) => {

  const { children , defaultValues } = props;
 
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(yourReducer, defaultValues);

  return (
    <WidgetContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </WidgetContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ContextProvider;
```

// implementation

```
   <ContextProvider
                  defaultValues={{
                    disabled: false,
                    icon: undefined,
                    text: "Hello",
                    badge: "100k",
                    styletype: "primary",
                    dir: "ltr",
                    }}
                >
    </ContextProvider>
```

Answer (score 2):

I liked @eric-burel's comment of using `throw` to narrow the type of the context.

But I wanted to use the hook with any context, so I made it generic.

`useSafeContext.ts`: (use this for any and all contexts with undefined)

```js
import { useContext, type Context } from "react";

export function useSafeContext<T>(Context: Context<T | undefined>) {
  const context = useContext(Context);
  if (context === undefined) throw new Error("Context Provider not found");
  return context as T;
}
```

---

##### An example of how to use it

`sampleContext.ts`: (use this as a template for your context)

```
import { createContext } from "react";

interface SampleState {
  sampleBoolean: boolean;
  sampleString: string;
}

// notice the undefined in generic and in the parameter
// this will be filtered out by [useSafeContext]
const SampleContext = createContext<SampleState | undefined>(undefined);

export default SampleContext;
```

`SamplePage.tsx`: (how to use it)

```js
function SamplePage() {
  // establish the state 
  const [{ sampleBoolean, sampleString }, setSampleState] = useState({ sampleBoolean: true, sampleString: "hello" });
  <SampleContext.Provider value={{ sampleBoolean, sampleString }}>
    <SampleSubpage />
  </SampleContext.Provider>;
}

function SampleSubpage() {
  // sampleState is SampleState and not undefined!
  const sampleState = useSafeContext(SampleContext);

  return (
    <ul>
      <li>Boolean {sampleState.sampleBoolean}</li>
      <li>String {sampleState.sampleString}</li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```