# UseContext returns undefined even though everything seems proper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a stack navigator which opens a screen and the screen uses Context and providers but `useContext` seems to return undefined.

We have this:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="preLogin" component={SomeScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="postLogin" component={SomeScreen2} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

In SomeScreen2 we have this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {SampleContextProvider} from './provider/SampleContext';
import WelcomeScreen from './welcome';

const SomeScreen2Container = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <SampleContextProvider>
        <WelcomeScreen navigation={navigation}/>
      </SampleContextProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default SomeScreen2Container;
```

SampleContext:

```
import React from 'react';

const SampleContext = React.createContext({a:"a",b:"b"});

const SampleContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <SampleContext.Provider>
      {children}
    </SampleContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { SampleContext, SampleContextProvider };
```

And in the WelcomeScreen I am using `useContext`:

```
import {SampleContext} from '../provider/SampleContext';
const ctx = useContext(SampleContext);
console.log("contextx=>", ctx);
```

It's undefined.

Feel free to ask for more information

Comment: You can only call hooks inside the components

Comment: @giotskhada You're right, but I think he already did that correctly otherwise he wouldn't be able to see that the context was undefined.

Comment: yeah yeah.. @giotskhada just an example. actually it's inside the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `SampleContext` file to this:

```
import React from 'react';

const SampleContext = React.createContext();

const SampleContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <SampleContext.Provider value={{a: 'a', b: 'b'}}>
      {children}
    </SampleContext.Provider>
  );
};

export {SampleContext, SampleContextProvider};
```

I defined your default context value in the provider value prop instead of as a parameter of `createContext`.

The value prop of your provider overrides the default value set in `createContext`. Meaning if you don't set `value` if you use a provider, the default value will override to undefined.

For more info look at this: [React.createContext point of defaultValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949099/react-createcontext-point-of-defaultvalue).

Comment: let me try this. will get back to you in 5mins

Answer (score 0):

In your welcome screen try doing this

```
import {SampleContext} from '../provider/SampleContext';
const {a,b}= useContext(SampleContext);
console.log("contextx=> ", a+' '+b);
```

i think destructuring the value might help you confirm if the sampleContext has the context values or not !

Comment: It doesn't. destructuring actually throwing errors. so that's why logging ctx. context is itself undefined.