# Providing values for react context twice on createContext and Provider component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, react-dom

React context usage with createContext does have an optional default value and most of the explanations on web are something like below.

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
const Context = createContext('Default Value');
```

then we have the `Provider` components on the context object which makes the child components capable to listen the context using `Consumer` components.

```
function Main() {
  const value = 'My Context Value';
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={value}>     /* Why is it mandatory to provide value attribute when we have the default value argument in createContext method. */
      <MyComponent />
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

and then Using Consumers we can get the values without worrying about using the props way of passing data in React js.

```
<Context.Consumer>
      {value => <span>{value}</span>}   //context value in anonymous inner function
    </Context.Consumer>
```

Why do we need to separate values for context using the `createContext` method and then on Provider component ? can't we use the value passed to `createContext` method itself ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which sort of component are you using? Functional or Class based component?

Comment: @MOHDSHAHZAIB- Using Functional component

Comment: Please have a look at this answer It might be your answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949099/react-createcontext-point-of-defaultvalue